# Can't make inline submit button when field with error

Tags: html, css

I have such problem.

I want to make submit and field inline always 
[image]

but when errors appears its turn to:

[image]

Here is html code of form when error appears:

```
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/wibiya_users/1" class="edit_user"></div>
  <div class="field">
   <div class="field_with_errors"><input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="text" value="email@mail.com1"></div>
  </div>
 <ul>
   <li>Email is invalid</li>
</ul>

 <div class="submit">
  <a href="#" onclick="$(this).closest('form').submit(); return false;">Edit</a>
 </div>

</form>
```

and this CSS:

```
  .field{
  display:inline;
  }
   .submit{
  display:inline;
  }
```

Tried to add:

```
    .field_with_errors{
   margin:0;
    diplay:inline;
  }
```

but didn't help.

Can someone suggest solution ?

Comment: @He, do you see Rails is adding fields_with_error class and it is making problems.

Comment: @He, I tried you code from jsfiddle and it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your Edit button above error message, and apply `float:left;` to `.field` . And it will work.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9sXDA/3/)

Comment: Position of controls depends on their parents elements too, I have set the position for the code you provided, may be its something else.
Is your website online?

Comment: Why dont use a table for proper positioning?

Comment: Is it right to make like that ? I thaught it is bad old technique.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is between your input and submit... So when it is not there everything is fine but when it is, it pushes down the elements after it, in this case the submit button.

Comment: So simply put the error message above or below both items and your done :)